# Mathematica Fourier Transform not responding

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to do Fourier Transformation on the following function Izzn, which is essentially just a lot of trigonometric function, whose Fourier transformation are all well defined. However, when I type `FourierTransform[Izzn,t,f]`, mathematica takes an unreasonably long time to evaluate. By unreasonable, I mean that it never gives the result but keeps evaluating. Some typical terms of Izz are posted below
[image]

```
 0.272441 Cos[1519.09 t]^2 + 2.69272 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
 0.383058 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 - 
 0.0419625 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.22 t] + 
 0.0494935 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
 0.910475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 
 0.407475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 2.42896 Cos[1519.24 t]^2 + 
 0.127629 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
 0.0659875 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
 0.351161 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 1.05013 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 
 0.5246 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
 0.0886742 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
 2.17117 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
 2.97282 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 5.7118 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 
 1.68453 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
 0.181303 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
 5.27604 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.26 t] + 
 0.928094 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.26 t]
```

Comment: Please can you post something we can work with in Mathematica? Make it so that I can copy and paste. A minimum working example is the usual format. I think you may have a list of numbers, but I can't see properly, if so, you need `Fourier` not `FourierTransform`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to post Izzn for people's use, but the website tell me that most of my post is code so it's not possible to add it. But as I said, and you can look in the picture, Izzn is just a large bunch of trigonometric functions of argument t.

Comment: Can you just post as few of the typical terms? Then I can see what happens.

Comment: Hi, I copied about one fifth of the terms here

Answer (score 2):

```
f[t_] = .272441 Cos[1519.09 t]^2 + 2.69272 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
   0.383058 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 - 
   0.0419625 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.22 t] + 
   0.0494935 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
   0.910475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 
   0.407475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 
   2.42896 Cos[1519.24 t]^2 + 
   0.127629 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   0.0659875 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   0.351161 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   1.05013 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 0.5246 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   0.0886742 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   2.17117 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   2.97282 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 5.7118 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 
   1.68453 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
   0.181303 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
   5.27604 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.26 t] + 
   0.928094 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.26 t];

FourierTransform[f[t], t, w]
```

[image]

Is this the result you expect? And it is lightning fast.

However, you do not actually need a Fourier Transform. Every Cos term will give 2 Delta functions and every Cos^2 term 3 Delta Functions and Cos Cos 4 Delta FunctionsE.g.:

```
FourierTransform[ Cos[a  t], t, w]
FourierTransform[Cos[a  t]^2, t, w]
FourierTransform[Cos[a  t] Cos[b t], t, w]
```

[image]

Therefore, as the Fourier Transform is linear, you can get the result by replacing

[image]

Note, due to numerical accuracy with machine numbers, you do not get exactly the same result as from Fourier Transform. For this you would need to use accurate numbers.

Comment: Did you try `InverseFourierTransform[%, w, t]` to verify it?

Comment: Hi, for this it is probably fast as there are only a few terms. But my problem is that for the full series (which you can see the picture), it seems very slow.

Comment: You do not actually need a Fourier Transform as your input consist only of Cos terms. Therefore you can get the solution by replacement. I added this possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a play with your data. I don't know what your data means but, as Daniel Huber points out, you can take the `FourierTransform`.

```
  ex = 0.272441 Cos[1519.09 t]^2 + 2.69272 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
   0.383058 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 - 
   0.0419625 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.22 t] + 
   0.0494935 Cos[1519.22 t]^2 + 
   0.910475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 
   0.407475 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.24 t] + 
   2.42896 Cos[1519.24 t]^2 + 
   0.127629 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   0.0659875 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   0.351161 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   1.05013 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 0.5246 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   0.0886742 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 
   2.17117 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.25 t] - 
   2.97282 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.25 t] + 5.7118 Cos[1519.25 t]^2 - 
   1.68453 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
   0.181303 Cos[1519.22 t] Cos[1519.26 t] - 
   5.27604 Cos[1519.24 t] Cos[1519.26 t] + 
   0.928094 Cos[1519.25 t] Cos[1519.26 t];
FourierTransform[ex, t, f]
```

[image]

As you can see it is full of delta functions which you may not want (or you may). There is a post somewhere that explains why `FourierTransform` does this.

If this is a time series analysis I suggest you use `LaplaceTransform` and then convert to Fourier. Thus

```
lt = LaplaceTransform[ex, t, s];
ft = lt /. s -> I ω // Chop
```

[image]

I don't know if this helps. I had some fun working out the poles of your expression thus

```
b = List @@ ft;
den = Denominator[#] & /@ b;
Solve[# == 0, ω] & /@ den
```

[image]

So you have lots of poles at high frequencies and low.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot.  Actually I guess the problem is about the length of the function. I posted the full Izzn just above your answer. Could you try it? I think for a small series, FourierTransform works fine, but when the function gets longer, it fails.